# How to set custom default ringtone on the selected list item in list View?

Tags: java, android

I use `RecyclerView` every list have its own sound.
I want when the user click on a list item that the specific sound is set as default ringtone.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a data structure with the sample sounds. Order them in the same order as your Recycler View elements. Add a onClickListener. Take the position received from the listener and send that sample to the media player.